# How to activate opened presentation?

Tags: c#, powerpoint

Hi 
Could some one help me for this problem: 
How to activate a presentation window by using its name?

```
  foreach (PPT.Presentation ppt in ppApp.Presentations)
    {
       if (ppt.Name == strTargetFileName)
            {
               //Then activate this ppt. How to do this?

                        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can launch a PowerPoint with [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx):

```
Process.Start(@"c:\users\foo\Documents\Bar.ppt");
```

If you need to actually launch it in slideshow mode, you can do:

```
Process.Start("powerpnt", "/s \"C:\\Users\\Foo\\Documents\\Bar.ppt\"");
```

Comment: how to activate unsaved pesentations?

Comment: OK, see what you're trying to do now. Anton's answer should help

Answer (score 1):

You should find window handle first with `FindWindow` function and when activate it with `SetForegroundWindow` function. Check [this](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/FindWindow.html) page, sample code there performs actually what you are looking for

Comment: This is quite useful, Thanks for the link :)

Answer (score 0):

first add a reference ( rigth click solution explorer to Microsoft PowerPoint XX Object)

```
   using MSPPOINT = Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint;
```

define a instance of the object

```
    MSPPOINT._Application pwpApp = new MSPPOINT.Application();
    MSPPOINT._Presentation pwpDoc = null;

    pwpApp.Activate();
    pwpDoc = pwpApp.Presentations.Open(@"D:\Temp\Document.pptx", Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse);
//enter code here
```

and do something with him..
Good Luck !